# Объединение строк в теге <caption>

Tags: html

Делаю таблицу под выгрузку с сайта в эксель. Проблема заключается в следующем, задаю шапку таблице тегом `<caption>` в нем использую теги `<br>` но в таком случае при выгрузке текст после тега `<br>` переносится на новую строку в excel. Возможно ли чтобы текст переносился но не создавал новую строку

пример

```
<caption>Текст <br> text</caption>
```

В экселе "текст" будет на первой строке "text" на второй строке. Нужно чтобы текст и text  были друг под другом но при этом номер строки был 1

Comment: Попробуйте при стилизации `<caption>` добавить свойство `white-space: pre;` и сделать перенос не тегом <br>, а как обычно - Enter-ом. Возможно, нужно будет подправить стили у `<caption>`, в частности шрифт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментарии товарищ UModeL дает дельный совет:

> Попробуйте при стилизации `<caption>` добавить свойство `white-space: pre;` и сделать перенос не тегом `<br>`, а как обычно - Enter-ом. Возможно, нужно будет подправить стили у `<caption>`, в частности шрифт.

Я посмотрел информацию на тему и вот что нашел: http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space, а также https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/white-space.
Но рекомендую MDN, т.к. на htmlbook информация не полная и устаревшая.
В приведенной ниже таблице указано поведение различных значений свойства `white-space`:
[image: Поведение различных значений свойства white-space]

Поэтому в вашем случае, вероятно, лучше подойдёт `white-space: break-spaces;`. Просто уберите `<br>` и оставьте 1 пробел.

```html
<caption style="white-space: break-spaces;">Текст text</caption>
```

Но, если вам нужно работать с Internet Explorer'ом, то тогда лучше использовать `white-space: pre;`.

```html
<caption style="white-space: pre;">Текст
text</caption>
```

Comment: млин, вопрос то интересный, а автор молчит. Ну, не устанавливать же себе теперь Excel, ради эксперимента))

Comment: Попробовал повторить проблему в excel 2019. Вообще не заметил проблемы. `<caption>` вообще не выгружается в качестве ячеки. Только как название для таблицы, но оно в строку идёт даже с `<br>`. Возможно конечно, что я просто не знаю как он выгружает, но как есть.